# MongoDB BI connector for qliksense

Tags: mongodb, qliksense

I am trying to set up MongoDB BI connector with Qliksense in Windows 10, but not getting through.

I've installed the connector setup and using cmd using admin access. 
Using this command:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.3\bin>mongodrdl.exe --host 180.xxx.xx.xxx --port xxxx --db xxx  --out schema.drdl  --username xxxx  --password xxxx  --authenticationDatabase xxx
```

and getting an error:

> Failed: can't create session: no servers available: server selection failed: context deadline exceeded

This is all I did. Can anyone suggest what steps am I missing or do I need to change anything?

Credentials are correct. I can login to the DB using Studio3T using the same.

Answer (score 0):

Shivesh, this error is usually an indication that mongosqld can not communicate with the target MongoDB cluster. Check that you have MongoDB running and it is accessible using mongodrdl.exe.